# reactjs - app doesn't change state after getting data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I'm building a React news app that gets its data from [News API](https://newsapi.org). On the home page I have a search bar where user enters key words to retreive from the API. When I enter the key word and press enter, the state changes and the results are visible on the page but then immediately it refreshes and displays the default page.

**App.js:**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { articles: [], keyword: ''};
    this.fetchNewsWithKeywords = this.fetchNewsWithKeywords.bind(this);
  }



  fetchNewsWithKeywords(keyword){
    searchForKeywords(keyword)
    .then(articles => this.setState({ articles: articles, keyword: keyword}))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router >
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container" >
          <Header/>
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => (

            <React.Fragment>
              <SearchNews fetchNewsWithKeywords = {this.fetchNewsWithKeywords.bind(this)}/>
              <NewsList articles = {this.state.articles}/>
            </React.Fragment>
          )} />
          <Route path="/top-headlines" component={TopHeadlines} />
          <Route path="/newest" component={Newest} />
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SearchNews.js**

```
class SearchNews extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  }
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    var str   = this.state.value;
    this.props.fetchNewsWithKeywords(str)
  }
  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  };  
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <TextField
        id="outlined-search"
        label="Search"
        type="search"
        className={classes.textField}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

**function for retrieving the data from API**

```
export async function searchForKeywords(keyword){
    var query = keyword


    var url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q="+ 
    encodeURIComponent(query) + 
    "&apiKey="+API_KEY;
    let result = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
    return result.articles.slice(0,20);
```

**NewsList.js**

```
export class NewsList extends Component {

  render() {
    return this.props.articles.map((article) => (
        <div className="gridContainer">
            <div className="gridItem" >
                <Article article = {article}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
  } 
}

export default NewsList
```

**Article.js**

```
class Article extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
        title,
        description,
        publishedAt,
        source,
        urlToImage,
        url
      } = this.props.article;
      const { classes } = this.props;
      let date = new Date(publishedAt).toLocaleString();
    return (
      <Card className={classes.card} >
        <CardActionArea href={url} target="_blank">
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={urlToImage}
                title={title}
            />
            <CardContent >
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography component="p">
                {description}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="caption">
                {source.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="caption">
                {date}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
);
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Article);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow kerq! What does you `NewsList` component look like? It's hard to say why it's not rendering anything without seeing how it's implemented.

Comment: Thank you! I just added NewsList.js & Article.js

Comment: I don't see anything apparently wrong. Do you see the state update if your write `console.log(this.state.articles);` in the render method of the `App` component?

Comment: No, [ ] is displayed in console.

Comment: Have you tried writing a `console.log` inside `.catch(() => this.setState({}));`? It might be that your fetch fails.

Comment: @kerq at what point did you verify your `setState` was called successfully and your state was updated with the results of your fetch?

Comment: @Tholle I just tried it, the fetch doesn't fail. It looks like the state is changed before the data is  retrieved from the API. Is this possible?

Comment: @TomFinney I tried debugging and I saw the data in state. I just started learning React so I'm new to this

Comment: @kerq Sorry, I meant at what point did you inspect the state and see it was valid. Did you put a console.log/breakpoint in here: `.then(articles => this.setState({ articles: articles, keyword: keyword}))` ?

Comment: @TomFinney yes I did, it displays brieftly the articles on the page and then refreshes and goes back to default

Comment: @kerq Well this is really quite weird! It seems like it should work but I'm guess I'm missing something obvious - lets try removing things! Can you get the rid of `this.forceUpdate()`? That might cause something weird to happen and additionally, I don't think you will need to call if like that because if the state has changed, it would have re-rendered anyway. If it's still not working after that, can you remove the `.catch` as well in case it is in fact erroring? It's the only thing I can see in the code that's clearing the state

Comment: @TomFinney I got rid of `this.forceUpdate()` and `.catch`. Still doesn't work :( I edited the `App.js` and it looks like this currently.

Comment: I think because onSubmit event lets try something to cancel form onSubmit event. Its make you page reload try add e.preventDefault() to first statement when on submit event occure

Comment: @ChanomFirst ohhh that's probably totally it. hahaha

Comment: @ChanomFirst that was the problem. Thank you very much everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
let result = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
return result.articles.slice(0,20);
```

You are awaiting the fetch and then `.then` to get the response as json, however, you are returning the `results.articles.slice` prior to that `response.json()` resolving?

Try:

```
let result = await fetch(url)
result = await result.json()
return result.articles.slice(0,20);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve my problem. I think that the data is fetched, state is set and then the page gets rerendered to default. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: Hmm.. I think the only thing that would cause that happen if you were to change the `key` prop on the App component and it would rebuild the component from scratch.